# IntelliJ - Stop auto-ignoring target directory

Tags: maven, svn, intellij-idea, ignore

I use IntelliJ IDE for development, and use the built in subversion (SVN) support for version control.

By default, IntelliJ adds the maven `target` directory to an "Ignored Files" list, so that you don't have to manually ignore it in the `svn:ignore` property on the project's directory in SVN. You can view that list in `File | Settings` under `Version Control | Ignored Files`.

The problem here occurs when we use our build tool, Jenkins, to perform a maven release. Jenkins checks out the project, builds it, then prepares the maven release by incrementing version numbers in `pom.xml`s and committing them. However, when it tries to commit, it gets errors because of local modifications because the `target` directory is not ignored in the SVN repo.

It took forever to figure out why it was saying there were local modifications to an ignored directory, but finally I found that it was because IntelliJ was showing the directory as ignored, but it wasn't actually ignored in our SVN repository.

Is there any way to disable the "automatically ignore target directory" functionality in IntelliJ so that we won't be misled into thinking the directory is ignored in our SVN repository?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. 
However, there are request that it should not be ignored if generated source are there, e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18710

As I understand the issue is that Ignored files is an internal mechanism that is not synced with SVN:ignore property. There is a request to add such sync:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128585